# API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x13fd1d7c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x1c4426e40>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

- I'm using Ionic 3 on iPhone 7 plus with iOS 11. When I run my App,
  and fill in some text/input fields (basic forms) the app freezes for
  a few seconds and becomes completely unresponsive (which isn't good,
  not to say the least).
- I noticed this error coming up in `Xcode`, maybe that's the problem.
  Has anyone else encountered similar errors?

`API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x13fd1d7c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x1c4426e40>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric`

Comment: I've seen the same error coming up

Comment: for me it 0x103412030, any idea on how to resolve it

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48006364/1387438) looks like a similar issue.

Comment: Did you ever find anything on this? On all other cases it's because the view is released early, but the keyboard isn't owned by the application so IDK.

Comment: It has been a long time. I have this issue, any idea?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: What does this error signifies? 0x13fd1d7c0 this varies for everyone i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Remove deprecated items from the forRoot config in `app.module.ts`

```
IonicModule.forRoot(),
```

Eg. remove these:

```
{
  scrollPadding: true,
  scrollAssist: false
}
```

See https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/config for more info.

Comment: This is not a solution, just tried this. Any other inputs?